# Dynamic export from SQL Server Database to Excel

Tags: excel, t-sql, import, ssis, export

I am building a patient record export system to extract data from SQL Server. The customer would like the data in the form of an Excel workbook.

The way that the data is held is such that the tables in the database are created dynamically and the column names change depending on the export parameters.

What I want to do is enumerate the tables in the database then export (or import) those tables (including column headers) to Excel in separate sheets into a single workbook.

SO:-

If Database is:-

```
dbo.table1 (name, address, postcode)
dbo.table2 (height, weight, headcirc)
```

I end up with an Excel workbook:-

```
Sheet1: Name Address Postcode
Sheet2: Height Weight, Headcirc
```

At the moment, every method I have looked at requires Excel to know the structure of the data it is receiving in advance. For a given export it is impossible to know the number of tables or the names of the columns in those tables in advance.

For example OPENROWSET requires column headers to be present in the Excel workbook.
SSIS seems to require fixed mappings to both the SQL Table columns and the Excel Workbook columns.

The only other approach I can think of is to export all tables to CSV using a dynamic BCP process, then to see if I can find some VBA that would allow me to assimilate all CSV files from a folder into a single Excel workbook as separate sheets - but this seems very clunky.

I am sure this must be possible - has anyone achieved this? What method would work?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably multiple ways to do this kind of thing. Some of these techniques may work, or may not work, depending on your setup, what versions of Excel and SQL Server you have installed, what other software you have installed, etc...

```
1) Export data to existing EXCEL file from SQL Server table
insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
    'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;', 
    'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]') select * from SQLServerTable


2) If you don't want to create an EXCEL file in advance and want to export data to it, use
EXEC sp_makewebtask 
    @outputfile = 'd:\testing.xls', 
    @query = 'Select * from Database_name..SQLServerTable', 
    @colheaders =1, 
    @FixedFont=0,@lastupdated=0,@resultstitle='Testing details'
```

32-bit and 64-bit drivers:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

You can run this VBA in Excel.

```
Sub TestMacro()

' Create a connection object.
Dim cnPubs As ADODB.Connection
Set cnPubs = New ADODB.Connection

' Provide the connection string.
Dim strConn As String

'Use the SQL Server OLE DB Provider.
strConn = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;"

'Connect to the Pubs database on the local server.
strConn = strConn & "DATA SOURCE=(local);INITIAL CATALOG=Name_of_your_DB;"

'Use an integrated login.
strConn = strConn & " INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"

'Now open the connection.
cnPubs.Open strConn

' Create a recordset object.
Dim rsPubs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset

With rsPubs
    ' Assign the Connection object.
    .ActiveConnection = cnPubs
    ' Extract the required records.
    .Open "SELECT * FROM Categories"
    ' Copy the records into cell A1 on Sheet1.
    Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rsPubs
    
    ' Tidy up
    .Close
End With

cnPubs.Close
Set rsPubs = Nothing
Set cnPubs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Or...

```
Sub ADOExcelSQLServer()
     
    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
     
    Server_Name = "your_server_name" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "your_database_name" ' Enter your  database name here
    User_ID = "" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "" ' Enter your password here
    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM Orders" ' Enter your SQL here
     
    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"
     
    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z500")
        .ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
    
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```